# How can I test code inside an Angular subscribe block without values being overwritten in subsequent subscribe blocks?

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs, ngx-socket-io

I'm using ngx-socket-io in an Angular application, and I have a component which includes various `.subscribe` blocks inside an `ngOnInit()`, which will subsequently run when data is received from the server

My problem is that when I call `ngOnInit()` inside my test suite, I am unable to test if a component variable is set to something inside one specific subscribe block, because it will be overwritten inside another subscribe block.

For example:

Component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setupBroadcastSubscriptions();
  }

  public setupBroadcastSubscriptions() {
    this.joinGameService.isHost()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
         this.hostName = data.hostName;
      });
    this.gameService.onUserDisconnection()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.toastr.info(data.message);
        this.playersInLobby = data.players;
        this.hostName = data.players.find(player => player.isHost).username;
      });
}
```

Test:

```
  test('when the first user enters a lobby, it should set the hostName to the user emitted from the server', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.hostName).toEqual('james');
  });
```

(Mocks in test suite are omitted for brevity)

I want to test what is happening specifically with `hostName` inside the `isHost` subscription. However, `hostName` will be overwritten inside the `onUserDisconnection` subscription.

One solution for this would be to create a method inside the subscribe blocks and test that method individually, but I don't want to test private methods.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: You say you've omitted the mocks for brevity, but they're the crucial part of this (as well as the usual [mre] requirement). If your mock methods return observables based on *subjects*, you can control exactly if and when they emit what values. See what I've done in https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/blob/254a1d61a23ba24c6728789f8032b7654b8321bd/src/app/table/table.component.spec.ts, for example

Answer (score 0):

If you utilise waitForAsync, you can use tick() to increment the timer in such a way that you can test the first subscribe, and then tick again and test the second subscribe.